# Upload file using Python AND Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

Here Is my html with jquery/ajax call section

```
<form id="upload-file" role="form" action="sendQuestions" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="modal-body">
    <label for="file"><b>Upload packet here</b></label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <p class="help-block">Upload a .pdf or .docx file you want to read.</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="upload-file-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Upload">Upload</button>
</div>
</form>

<script>

$(function() {
$('#upload-file-btn').click(function() {
    var form_data = new FormData($('#upload-file')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'abc.py',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
    });
});
});
```

Now here is my python abc.py section

```
#!C:/Python27/python.exe
#print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n";
#//20256542

import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import requests

form = cgi.FieldStorage()


fileitem = form.getvalue('file')

# Test if the file was uploaded
if fileitem.filename:
   # strip leading path from file name to avoid 
   # directory traversal attacks
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename.replace("\\", "/" ))
   open(fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())

   print 'PASS'

else:
   print 'FAILED'
```

Now when my `ajax` calls the `abc.py` I got the error :
Error at:

```
 if fileitem.filename:

<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
  args = ("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'",)
  message = "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'"
```

i understand that through request I think we cant access the file in abc.py , if i do the same by `form action` I can upload the file. But not incase of this `ajax call` .  Please help

Comment: Looks like your form.getvalue is method and it must be called with brakets: fileitem = form.getvalue('file')

Comment: @Andrey Shokhin yes that was a definite mistake , I edited the code same. But no luck . Thanks a lot for your help .

Comment: @curiousguy do you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

If your input field is a file type, accessing the value via the `getvalue()` method reads the entire file in memory as a string.
Instead of that, use file name attribute.

`form = cgi.FieldStorage()`

`fileitem = form['file']  #attribute is input filed name`